# What is the equivalent for @@Error in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ProcError
```

I have the above code in SQL Server.I am unable to find an oracle equivalent for @@Error.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What does `@@Error` do or return?

Comment: Non-Zero Value is populated in @@Error if an error occurs in the previous sql statement

Comment: If an error occurs, an exception is thrown in PL/SQL. You need to add an [exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-0502DC1A-F0A5-4180-A912-6A5CDC855F56)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Kfinity's offering of an exception handler to trap an error raised by a SQL statement (or PL/SQL statement for that matter).

It might also be helpful to know that the direct correlation of @@Error in PL/SQL is SQLCODE. If non-zero (which it only is when invoked from within an exception handler) it gives you the error code. If 0, well, then....no error!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do error handling. In PL/SQL it usually looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  ...do something...
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN -- check for a specific exception
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('No data found exception caught');
WHEN OTHERS THEN -- catch any exception
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Unexpected error');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace); 
  RAISE; -- re-raise the exception after logging it
END;
```

You can either do this for your entire PL/SQL block that you're currently working with (function, procedure, etc), or you can wrap a single statement in an anonymous PL/SQL block with an exception handler if you want more of a TRY..CATCH functionality.